# build a simple application able to run some Tasks in a specific order

Tags: python, class, apache-spark, oop, pyspark

I am building a simple application in python able to run some Tasks in a specific order.

To achieve that, i am creating an executor which will take care of which task to execute, and a base Task class with the common abstraction in Python. Something like this.

```
class Executor(object):
    def __init__(self, tasks=[]):
        self.tasks = tasks
    def run(self):
        # do stuff
```

```
class Task():
    def __init__(self, source_df, start_date, end_date):
        self.source_df = source_df
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date

    def filter_source_data():
        #return a filtered dataframe

    def transform ():
        #return cleaned data

    def load_data():
        #load data in hive table
```

The executor should run the whole pipeline or an individual Task if we specify it on the command line as an argument.

Task list can be  any or all of these : ['filter','transform', 'load']

I am stucked/confused how to implement the solution. i am very new to object oriented programming design.

Comment: So, are you confused about how to connect the command line to the class? Or doing the work like filtering, cleaning, and such?

Comment: No issues with filter, transform and loading logic.

Comment: I need to complete the executor class in such a way that it should run whole pipeline or individual task provided in task list.